# Ajax request vs kendoUI Datasource

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

I am new to Kendo ui, Can any one help in understaning what is the deifference between ajax and kendo UI datasource

Comment: KendoUI DataSources uses ajax for getting the data. It's just a question of making it _simpler_  and more _convenient_ for you (you don't have to deal with ajax interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Kendo UI datasource is an ***object*** in JavaScript that abstracts AJAX communication in your web application.

AJAX is a client-side ***technique*** used to communicate with a server in web applications.

Comment: Thanks really helpful, So I can make use of kendo UI Datasource instead of Ajax technique, can please tell me pros and cons by using kendo UI Datasource instead of Ajax.